# Scene Builder 2.0 doesn't start

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I installed Scene Builder 2.0 on my new computer with Windows 7, 16 GB RAM and Intel E3.

But I can't start Scene Builder. Nothing happens when I'm clicking on the desktop symbol.

```
I tried it this way:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0\app>java -jar SceneBuilderApp.jar
Feb 23, 2015 6:31:57 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows R
egCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
loader.getController()=com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.info.InfoPanelController@2025ff13
loader.getLocation()=jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Oracle/JavaFX%20Scene%20Builder%202.0/app/
SceneBuilderApp.jar!/com/oracle/javafx/scenebuilder/app/info/InfoPanel.fxml
loader.getController()=com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.DocumentWindowController@795ecdbe
loader.getLocation()=jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Oracle/JavaFX%20Scene%20Builder%202.0/app/
SceneBuilderApp.jar!/com/oracle/javafx/scenebuilder/app/DocumentWindow.fxml
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:363)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:303)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:875)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$147(LauncherImpl.java:15
7)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$48/1177096266.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Oracle/JavaFX
%20Scene%20Builder%202.0/app/SceneBuilderApp.jar!/com/oracle/javafx/scenebuilder/app/DocumentWindow.
fxml
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.panel.util.AbstractFxmlWindowController.makeRoo
t(AbstractFxmlWindowController.java:114)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.panel.util.AbstractWindowController.getRoot(Abs
tractWindowController.java:91)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.panel.util.AbstractWindowController.getScene(Ab
stractWindowController.java:111)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.panel.util.AbstractWindowController.getStage(Ab
stractWindowController.java:134)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.DocumentWindowController.openWindow(DocumentWindowCont
roller.java:1088)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.handleLaunch(SceneBuilderApp.java:418)

        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.AppPlatform.requestStartGeneric(AppPlatform.java:139)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.AppPlatform.requestStart(AppPlatform.java:106)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.start(SceneBuilderApp.java:371)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(LauncherImpl.java:8
21)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$51/1800502861.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(PlatformImpl.java:323)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$44/1190900417.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(PlatformImpl.java:292)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/846381162.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(PlatformImpl.java:291)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/99550389.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/1401420256.run(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Oracle/JavaFX
%20Scene%20Builder%202.0/app/SceneBuilderApp.jar!/com/oracle/javafx/scenebuilder/app/info/InfoPanel.
fxml
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.panel.util.AbstractFxmlPanelController.makePane
l(AbstractFxmlPanelController.java:93)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.panel.util.AbstractPanelController.getPanelRoot
(AbstractPanelController.java:130)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.DocumentWindowController.controllerDidLoadFxml(Documen
tWindowController.java:985)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.panel.util.AbstractFxmlWindowController.makeRoo
t(AbstractFxmlWindowController.java:110)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Oracle/JavaFX
%20Scene%20Builder%202.0/app/SceneBuilderKit.jar!/com/oracle/javafx/scenebuilder/kit/editor/panel/in
spector/editors/StringAutoSuggestEditor.fxml
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.panel.inspector.editors.EditorUtils.loadFxml(Ed
itorUtils.java:483)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.panel.inspector.editors.EditorUtils.loadFxml(Ed
itorUtils.java:463)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.panel.inspector.editors.AutoSuggestEditor.preIn
it(AutoSuggestEditor.java:124)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.panel.inspector.editors.AutoSuggestEditor.<init
>(AutoSuggestEditor.java:118)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.panel.inspector.editors.AutoSuggestEditor.<init
>(AutoSuggestEditor.java:103)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.panel.inspector.editors.ControllerClassEditor.<
init>(ControllerClassEditor.java:51)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.info.InfoPanelController.performInitialization(InfoPan
elController.java:186)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.info.InfoPanelController.controllerDidLoadFxml(InfoPan
elController.java:173)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.panel.util.AbstractFxmlPanelController.makePane
l(AbstractFxmlPanelController.java:89)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException:
file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Oracle/JavaFX%20Scene%20Builder%202.0/app/SceneBuilderKit.jar!/com/
oracle/javafx/scenebuilder/kit/editor/panel/inspector/editors/StringAutoSuggestEditor.fxml

        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2595)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2565)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2403)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.panel.inspector.editors.EditorUtils.loadFxml(Ed
itorUtils.java:481)
        ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2560)
        ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.panel.inspector.editors.AutoSuggestEditor.initi
alize(AutoSuggestEditor.java:142)
        ... 46 more
Exception running application com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp

C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0\app>java -jar SceneBuilderKit.jar
kein Hauptmanifestattribut, in SceneBuilderKit.jar

C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0\app>
```

What I have to do for resolving this problem?

Comment: What's your java version?

Comment: 1.8.0_31... But Scene Builder has its own JRE?

Comment: I had a complete different problem with starting scene builder 2.0 on MacOS. +1 for hinting me to start SceneBuilder on the command line which enabled me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me: https://deltadata.wordpress.com/2013/12/25/javafx-scene-builder-failed-to-create-jvm-fix/

But I have to try that twice.